# Simple way to change text size in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have RelativeLayout with RelativeLayout title bar:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    style="@style/TitleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    style="@style/WindowCaption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="caption"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
    style="@style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:onClick="save"
    android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

On a small screens the button gets on top of the text:

[image]

I want to resize text, or button to make all of them properly visible.
And I want the text was is on the centre.

**Can I do it somehow using only style and layout tools?**

Or the only way is to programmatically change the text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/te1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:text="Countfdddgd "
    android:textSize="40dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"   
        android:height="45dp"
        android:text="Accounts"
        android:width="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good idea! Why I didn't thought of that? Thank you!